# Send multiple data from rails to react

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, axios

My rails api is following the below.

```
def index_all
    page_size = params[:pageSize].to_i
    page = params[:page].to_i * page_size
    users = User.limit(page_size).offset(page)
    render json: users,
           include: %i[inflow_souce job_area user_evaluations evaluations]
  end
```

I want to add this parameter.

```
users_length = User.all.length
```

I tried this code but it was wrong.

```
page_size = params[:pageSize].to_i
    page = params[:page].to_i * page_size
    users = User.limit(page_size).offset(page)
    users_length = User.all.length
    render json: users && users_length
           include: %i[inflow_souce job_area user_evaluations evaluations]
```

How can I fix it ?

Note: can't wrap {}, because of client side problem.

Comment: Does `render json: users, meta: { length: users_length }, include: %i[inflow_souce job_area user_evaluations evaluations]` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry..

```
def index_all
    page_size = params[:pageSize].to_i
    page = params[:page].to_i * page_size
    users = User.limit(page_size).offset(page)
    users_length = User.all.length
    render json: {
             users: users,
             users_length: users_length,
           },
           include: %i[inflow_souce job_area user_evaluations evaluations]
  end
```

It worked..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).